# no background for <a> in ie6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, background

Don't know how to fix it. I've trying to make different logotypes, depending on class of the  tag. The html is:

```
<div id="header"> 
    <a href="/index.php" id="logo" class="cet"> 
        <h1 id="l">title</h1> 
    </a>
</div>
```

And css is:

```
#header {
    height:204px;
    background: url(../img/il-01.jpg) no-repeat  400px 2em;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}
#header #logo {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:2em;
    top:3em;
    width:355px;
    height:107px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#header #logo.cat { background: url( ../img/logo_cat.png) no-repeat -1px top; }
#header #logo.cet {background: url( ../img/logo_cet.png) no-repeat -10px -40px;}
```

And if the class is set for 'cat' everything is just fine, but if it's set for 'cet' i can not see the image in IE6. In any other browser the background displays correctly.

The background images are little different by size, can it be the problem?

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Don't use Internet Explorer 6?

Comment: Does this work in other browsers?

Comment: I wish i could not use IE6, but it's a whim of some political structures in Russia *palmface*

Answer (score 4):

You are not allowed mix lengths and keywords for the `background(-positon)`. Old CSS versions didn't allow it, so older browsers may not support it. Instead of

```
#header #logo.cat { background: url( ../img/logo_cat.png) no-repeat -1px top; }
```

use

```
#header #logo.cat { background: url( ../img/logo_cat.png) no-repeat -1px 0; }
```

BTW, You need to check your HTML. A block element such as `<h1>` may not be inside a link (`<a>`).

Comment: but if i use mixed lengths and keywords, like in 'cat' it works in IE6! but 'cet' doesn't work.

Comment: I mean, only 2 last are different, but 'cat' class works in IE6, and 'cet' doesn't

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. "cat" doesn't have mixed keywords and lengths in your example.

Comment: well, i tried different values of background position for 'cet' class, but it doesn't work in IE6

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your PNG file for cet. Can you see the image when you open the file directly in IE?

Comment: strange... if i change
#header #logo.cet {background: url( ../img/logo_cet.png) no-repeat -10px -40px;}

to

#header #logo.cet {background: url( ../img/logo_cat.png) no-repeat -1px 0px;}

it doesn't work again in IE6

Comment: i can open the file in any browser.
i tried to add a background color, and i can not see the color in IE6, damn

Comment: Sorry, I'm out out ideas. You'll probably need to post a URL.

Comment: new.master-cet.customs.ru
Also, i added red border to the a#logo but no result again

Comment: the problem was in order of classes, i placed 'cet' berofe 'cat' and it fixed the problem